# Кастомная ошибка в HTML

Tags: html, http-status-code-404

Недавно, мой приятель сделал сайт, но, когда проверяешь его в Check-Host (HTTP) — показывает "Ошибка сервера" и ошибку "666 (*рандом текст*). При этом всём, на сайт спокойно входит. (Это не связано с клаудфлейр) Как такое же можно реализовать, просто тоже такую штучку хочется, а друг, как такое сделать — не говорит. Пример [тут](https://check-host.net/check-http?host=https%3A%2F%2Fddos.systems%2F).

/ upd. В консоле Chrome показывает 2 ошибки: одна адресует на favicon.ico — 404 Not Found;
вторая ошибка — 666. /

Comment: А в чем же  проблема?

Comment: Смотри, когда проверяешь сайт на Чек-Хосте — показывает ошибку 666 (HTTP метод).

Comment: Вроде через [http_response_code](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.http-response-code.php) можно но я не проверял

Comment: А проблема то в чем? Можно прямо вопрос сформулировать, чтобы не приходилось догадываться?